# How to use stored procedure inside the stored procedure in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have been working on my code for our activity in our major comp sci subject. The task asks to update a certain field in the table in postgresql using stored procedure
[image]

I have already create a gettopemp() to retrieved the data in the table, and I want to retrieve the information of gettopemp() to my new stored procedure updatetopemp(). How to use stored procedure inside the stored procedure ???

Comment: As a general rule, don't paste images of code - paste actual code itself. Nobody wants to type up tens of lines of code just to replicate your problem

Comment: Please post code as *text*, not as image.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I see at least two errors in your blurry image. 1) the equality operator is `=` in SQL, not `==`. 2) Variables are assigned using `:=` not `set`  Also: what is the error message you get? [Edit] your question and add that information as [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) don't post additional information in comments

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a function name as a parameter and call that in your code, you'll have to use [*dynamic SQL*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).